# How to catch the notification to pause audio

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter, avplayeritem

I want to pause when an notification popup from the top of screen or when a call come in.

I use AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem.

How to implement it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944411/how-to-get-notified-when-the-status-bar-height-changes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530934/ios-notification-of-when-a-call-is-taking-place

Comment: I do not think they are same problems

Answer (score 0):

For incoming call and your app is on the foreground you can check 
[Call events in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383222/call-events-in-iphone)
or [iOS: showing an alert when getting a call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395130/ios-showing-an-alert-when-getting-a-call)

Answer (score 0):

I think **AVAudioSession** maybe can resolve it: [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875)